# Debian Fail2ban action.d and filter.d scripts

Tags: debian, fail2ban

I have a debian wheezy server on which I use Fail2ban that was loaded with the package installer.  I noticed that while the version on my server (0.8.6-3wheezy3) is current, it does not match up with the fail2ban.org web site version.  In particular, the action.d and filter.d scripts in my distribution are quite old, and has many fewer, compared to the ones on the fail2ban distribution.  I downloaded and extracted them from here: (http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Are these compatible?  Can I update my scripts with the ones from the fail2ban.org distribution?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are most likely not compatible, as new features have been added to the `fail2ban` engine which I guess have been used by the distributed filter scripts.

It's usally not a problem if the scripts are older,  as long as they work for your setup. If that's not enough, you would either need to build your own version or try to use the `jessie` or even `sid` [packages](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=fail2ban) (which I wouldn't like to do).